# Device says bootloader unlocked but OEM unlock option can enabled and disabled?

Tags: rooting, bootloader, xiaomi, bootloader-lock, miui

I have a Redmi Note 3 (INDIAN VARIANT Kenzo/Snapdragon variant running on Marshmellow 6.0.1 with MIUI Global 10.2) on which I performed an bootloader unlocking procedure via the tool XiaoMiTool V2 from [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/tool-miunlocktool-unlock-bootloader-t3782444) since the official method kept denying me for some reason

I also want to let you know that during the procedure i left the *oem unlocking option disabled* and ran the tool

So after the device's bootloader was unlocked (ss attached)[image]
[image]

I noticed that the OEM unlocking option was still active (meaning I can flip the button and it will just ask for the pass and warn me and enable the option: again ss attached)

[image]

[image]

**So my question is is my device properly unlocked? OR Did I mess up with procedure ?**
I know i could dial `*#*#7378423#*#*` *(which doesn't work in miui devices)* or using *fastboot method* [mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73567/how-to-check-if-your-bootloader-is-unlocked)- *but the problem is that my device's usb port is damaged in a way that charging works but MTP or any other option doesn't (Yeah I tried multiple usb cables, brought a brand new from official store and multiple devices)* or is there any app to do that ?

**EDIT :**
Okay now I tried by adjusting the chord into the port and running `fastboot getvar unlocked`(ss attached)

[image]

Now what does this mean ? Is it still locked ?

I would really thankful if someone can help

Comment: I haven't tried this myself. See if this helps [How to Execute ADB Commands over WiFi without USB or Root](https://www.droidviews.com/adb-over-wifi-without-usb/). according to this site you can connect to your device with adb fastboot via Wi-Fi. Good Luck

Comment: this can't work. you can't authorize RSA-key without usb-cable. btw that is adb only, not related to fastboot

Comment: As I said I haven't tried but the site claims you can  connect. BTW according to that site you can run adb reboot bootloader to boot into fastboot.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question... In most devices (not all) the OEM Unlock toggle becomes unusable once the device is unlocked, in other devices it just does nothing but what you show. Your device is either locked or unlocked, there is no in-between or "properly" unlocked. The OEM Unlocking toggle only says if you can unlock or not, once it the device is unlocked, it does not actually perform any lock/unlock function, and once a device is unlocked it has no function.

Comment: OEM unlocking should affect FRP it will disable FRP as far as it concerns the google play account. but be aware on Xiaomi devices the only way to disable FRP completely is remove MI account from device

Comment: @acejavelin that's confusion all about my device says its bootloader is unlocked but the option is not disabled (or grayed out)

Comment: The confusion is your understanding of what the "OEM Unlocking" switch is... It is just a toggle that allows you to unlock the bootloader and It has no other function and does not lock or unlock anything, and once the bootloader is actually unlocked, it does nothing and it's current setting is not relevant to any functionality. In most other devices I am familiar with (Pixel and Motorola devices), once the bootloader is unlocked this switch is grayed out and cannot be changed, but it seems Redmi didn't exactly implement it that way.

Comment: @Sruly thank you for your insight on wireless adb (which to say i had no view of ) but as alecxs mentioned RSA fingerprinting (which in i revoked coz i used multiple device ) is required and fastboot doesn't work without cable connection can you suggest any app ?

Comment: @acejavelin P.S I forgot to mention that i didn't enable this option (Allow oem unlock) while i was unlocking

Comment: Whether you toggled the setting or not, it had to be off in order for you to actually perform the unlock in the bootloader with fastboot. After you are unlocked it serves no purpose and the setting is not relevant. If you devices USB port is damaged, how did you unlock it? The actual unlocking process must be done via your computer with fastboot. I don't know how much more I can add to this conversation, I have given the answer multiple times.

Comment: @acejavelin i recently saw multiple Redmi unlocking procedure for the same device and all them had toggled the switch & as for the port it wasn't damaged when i did procedure (my device's screen was cracked during that time) and i gave it for repair after which it was damaged also pls see the post below

Comment: *OEM lock 'has to be off'* mean *OEM **un**lock 'enabled'* + *MiUnlock 'enabled'* (for Xiaomi devices) as acejavelin already stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you enable the `Allow OEM unlocking` option before proceeding to unlock bootloader
I tried by adjusting the chord into the port and running `fastboot getvar unlocked` which gave no value meaning the device is still locked (ss attached) [image]

Even though it says nothing (unlocked : YES etc), I did switch the toggle on for `Allow OEM unlocking` before proceeding to flash just to be on a safer side and successfully flashed twrp recovery and carbonrom and the device is running well

Comment: Does this answer your question – or was it rather meant as an additional detail of the question? In the former case I don't get it – in the latter you should rather edit your question and put it there ;)